# Pumpkins are not producing male flowers

Tags: pumpkins

I haven't seen a single male flower this season and as a result females are shriveling and dropping off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ...Check to be sure you haven't got a variety bred to only produce female flowers, which would require a different variety to make male flowers. There is a previous question about the same, but it resolved itself. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/34240/6806